# Why is mongoose not saving these "options"

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

NOTE: All dates are waffle, i'm just testing.

The options from the discord command are not being saved into the mongodb database. When looking at the database viewer, it seems that it's not recognising that the new options aren't a thing, sorry if i didn't explain it to well.

Schema: gameInfos.js

```
    const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');
    
    let gameInfos = new Schema({
        Name: String,
        ReleaseDate: String,
        TimeToRelease: Number,
        ImageURL: String,
        Achievements: Number,
        TimeToComplete: Number
    })
    
    module.exports = model("gameInfos", gameInfos)
```

[View of data in database - ESSENTIAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk9d2.png)

Main command

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const gameInfos = require('../../schemas/gameInfos')

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("add-game-release")
    .setDescription(
      "Add a game to the game release database. All game releases will be sent in #new-games! ADMINS ONLY"
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("gamename")
        .setDescription(
          'Please provide the name of the game that you wish to use. For example: "Cyberpunk 2077"'
        )
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addIntegerOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("releaseday")
        .setDescription(
          "Please provide the release day. EG: 21 in 21st of November 2024."
        )
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("releasemonth")
        .setDescription(
          "Please provide the release month. EG: November in 21st of November 2024"
        )
        .setRequired(true)
        .addChoices(
          { name: "Janurary", value: "1" },
          { name: "February", value: "2" },
          { name: "March", value: "3" },
          { name: "April", value: "4" },
          { name: "May", value: "5" },
          { name: "June", value: "6" },
          { name: "July", value: "7" },
          { name: "August", value: "8" },
          { name: "September", value: "9" },
          { name: "October", value: "10" },
          { name: "November", value: "11" },
          { name: "December", value: "12" }
        )
    )
    .addIntegerOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("releaseyear")
        .setDescription(
          "Please provide the release year. EG 2024 in 21st November 2024"
        )
        .setRequired(true)
        .setMinValue(4)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("imageurl")
        .setDescription(
          "Please provide a link for the game cover. This is required."
        )
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addIntegerOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("achievements")
        .setDescription(
          "Please provide the number of achivements. 0 if there are none."
        )
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addIntegerOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("timetocomplete")
        .setDescription("Please provide the time to complete/get platnium IN HOURS")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const { options } = interaction;
    let currentDate = new Date();
    console.log(currentDate);
    const gameTitle = options.getString("gamename");
    const day = options.getInteger("releaseday");
    const month = options.getString("releasemonth");
    const year = options.getInteger("releaseyear");
    const imageURL = options.getString("imageURL")
    const achievements = options.getInteger("achievements")
    const timetocomplete = options.getInteger("timetocomplete")

    let releaseDate = `${month}/${day}/${year}`;

    // To calculate the time difference of two dates
    let Difference_In_Time =
      new Date(releaseDate).getTime() - new Date(currentDate).getTime();

    // To calculate the no. of days between two dates
    let Difference_In_Days = Math.round(
      Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
    );

    gameInfos.create({
      Name: gameTitle,
      ReleaseDate: releaseDate,
      TimeToRelease: Difference_In_Days,
      ImageURL: imageURL,
      achievements: achievements,
      timetocomplete: timetocomplete
    });

    console.log(timetocomplete)

    interaction.reply("Sent to console.");
    console.log(
      `${chalk.bold.blue(
        "[LOG]"
      )} A game release reminder called ${gameTitle} was added to the database. The release date is ${day}/${month}/${year}. That's ${Difference_In_Days} days away from now.`
    );
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

---

###### Your `Mongoose` Schema setup is fully correct but you have a couple of problems in your implementations. Let's go together

---

- ###### Typo in Schema Fields

*According to your schema setup, `(Achievements, and TimeToComplete)` this too filled you did not use it correctly. You're using lowercase versions `(achievements and timetocomplete)`. MongoDB is case-sensitive, so these should match.*

#### But update your schema as follows:

```js
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

let gameInfos = new Schema({
    Name: String,
    ReleaseDate: String,
    TimeToRelease: Number,
    ImageURL: String,
    Achievements: Number,
    TimeToComplete: Number
});

module.exports = model("gameInfos", gameInfos);
```

---

- ###### Mismatch in Option Names

*When retrieving options from the interaction, you're using `options.getString("imageURL")`, however, the option is defined as `imageurl` in your command builder. Verify that the names correspond. Also, ensure that you are using the correct casing for other option names in the `execute function`*

Update the line like this:

```js
const imageURL = options.getString("imageurl");
```

---

- ###### Data Types for Time Calculations

*Although you are giving a string `Difference_In_Days` to the `execute function`, the `TimeToRelease` field in the schema is defined as a number. To ensure similarity, turn it into a number*

```js
TimeToRelease: Number(Difference_In_Days),
```

---

###### Note: Do check to understand yourself `Math.round(2.8)` always return type of `number`.

@I hope your code will work if you do set it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

use `await` inside async function where before creating data through mongoose model.

```
async fn() {
    await gameInfos.create({
          Name: gameTitle,
          ReleaseDate: releaseDate,
          TimeToRelease: Difference_In_Days,
          ImageURL: imageURL,
          achievements: achievements,
          timetocomplete: timetocomplete
        });
    }
```